# Is it possible to use higher version of java than mentioned?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Can I use higher `java version` (17) on my machine than mentioned in existing (11) spring boot project's pom.xml ?

will it create any problem ?

Comment: Java is known for its backwards compatibility so mostly no. I say mostly because java 17 has definitely deprecated a lot of old features for removal and if you're spring framework uses that you will get a lot of warnings . See the [Deprecated List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/deprecated-list.html) and the [JEPS](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/17/jeps-since-jdk-11) for latest updates

Answer (score 1):

Backward Compatibility

Java versions are expected to be binary backwards-compatible. For example, JDK 8 can run code compiled by JDK 7 or JDK 6. It is common to see applications leverage this backwards compatibility by using components built by different Java version.

The compiler is not backwards compatible because bytecode generated with Java5 JDK won’t run in Java 1.4 jvm (unless compiled with the -target 1.4 flag). But the JVM is backwards compatible, as it can run older bytecodes. JDK’s are (usually) forward compatible.

See: https://alanxelsys.com/php/what-is-meant-by-backward-compatible-in-java.html